# python np.where referencing previous value in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, numpy, loops

In pandas df I want to create a column of values on condition which references this exact column's previous value. So in a basic loop this would look like this.

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df["DESIRED"][i-1] ==0 :
        df["DESIRED"][i]=df["price_b"][i]  
    elif abs(df.iloc[i-1,p]-df["DESIRED"][i-1])>10:
        df["DESIRED"][i] = 0
    else:
         df["DESIRED"][i] = df["DESIRED"][i-1]
```

Result:

[image]

We have a price at "product", signals at "entry_b" and entry price at "price_b". We want to be in the trade as long as absolute value between "product" and entry price is less than 10, returning the entry price. In the loop I do that by checking previous value.

However, for loop is taking x1000s more time to calculate than np.where() function. I feel there is a smart way to solve this with np.where() .ffill() .bfill() and maybe .roll() using numpy which would be much faster. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `np.where` is not a 'row' iterator!  The `where` arguments are evaluated in full before being passed to the function.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware, but there must be some sort of workaround using flags or roll maybe? It's just the speed advantage is huge vs the loop.

Comment: You have to, somehow, express the condition based purely on values in the existing columns.  `Desired` does not exist when you create the arguments for `where`.  Sometimes its possible to use things like `np.cumsum` or `np.maximum.accumulate`.

Comment: What is the variable `p`?